# Spring.net IoC - Vary injected class by state

Tags: dependency-injection, spring.net

I'm attempting to inject a dependency that varies by the state passed in.  For example, if the state is Wisconsin, I want to inject one class, but if it's Illinois, I want another.  It's not 1-for-1, but 7 states for one and 3 for another.

Is there a way in Spring.net to have a list of values to check against in the config xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the subject of chapter 6.1 "Mapping runtime values to abstractions" of the book [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://manning.com/seemann/). The solution suggested there is to use an `Abstract Factory`. Your abstract factory might look like:

```
public interface IStateAlgorithmFactory
{
    IStateAlgorithm Create(string state);
}
```

And inject this factory on your consumer that knows which state to process. To get an `IStateAlgorithm` his consumer then calls y

```
alg = _factory.Create("Illnois");
```

Optionally, you could create a simple factory that maps state names to instances managed by your spring container if you want full configuration control.

#### Simple example

I imagine you have several classes that implement a certain `IStateAlgorithm`:

```cs
public interface IStateAlgorithm
{
    string ProcessState(string stateName);
}

public class EchoingStateAlgorithm : IStateAlgorithm
{
    public string ProcessState(string stateName)
    {
        return stateName;
    }
}

public class ReverseEchoingStateAlgorithm : IStateAlgorithm
{
    public string ProcessState(string stateName)
    {
        return new string(stateName.Reverse().ToArray());
    }
}
```

And that there is a certain `Consumer` that needs to pick an algorithm based on a runtime value. The consumer can be injected with a factory, from which it can retrieve the algorithm it needs:

```cs
public class Consumer
{
    private readonly IStateAlgorithmFactory _factory;

    public Consumer(IStateAlgorithmFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public string Process(string state)
    {
        var alg = _factory.Create(state);
        return alg.ProcessState(state);
    }
}
```

A simple factory implementation would simply switch on the state value, use an if, or look in internal list:

```cs
public interface IStateAlgorithmFactory
{
    IStateAlgorithm Create(string state);
}

public class StateAlgorithmFactory : IStateAlgorithmFactory
{
    private string[] _reverseStates = new[] {"Wisconsin", "Alaska"};

    public IStateAlgorithm Create(string state)
    {
        if(_reverseStates.Contains(state))
            return new ReverseEchoingStateAlgorithm();

        return new EchoingStateAlgorithm();
    }
}
```

#### Spring.Net Configurable example

If you would like to be able to configure your `IStateAlgorithm` in your spring configuration, you can introduce a `LookupStateAlgorithmFactory`. This example assumes that your `IStateAlgorithm`s are stateless and can be shared among consumers:

```cs
public class LookupStateAlgorithmFactory : IStateAlgorithmFactory
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, IStateAlgorithm> _stateToAlgorithmMap;
    private readonly IStateAlgorithm _defaultAlgorithm;

    public LookupStateAlgorithmFactory(IDictionary<string, IStateAlgorithm> stateToAlgorithmMap, 
                                        IStateAlgorithm defaultAlgorithm)
    {
        _stateToAlgorithmMap = stateToAlgorithmMap;
        _defaultAlgorithm = defaultAlgorithm;
    }

    public IStateAlgorithm Create(string state)
    {
        IStateAlgorithm alg;
        if (!_stateToAlgorithmMap.TryGetValue(state, out alg))
            alg = _defaultAlgorithm;

        return alg;
    }
}
```

The xml config could be:

```xml
<object id="lookupFactory"
        type="LookupStateAlgorithmFactory, MyAssembly">
  <constructor-arg ref="echo" />
  <constructor-arg>
    <dictionary key-type="string" value-type="IStateAlgorithm, MyAssembly">
      <entry key="Alaska" value-ref="reverseEcho"/>
      <entry key="Wisconsin" value-ref="reverseEcho"/>
    </dictionary>
  </constructor-arg>
</object>

<object id="echo" type="EchoingStateAlgorithm, MyAssembly" />
<object id="reverseEcho" type="ReverseEchoingStateAlgorithm, MyAssembly" />
```

Comment: As you already mentioned the dependency on `IApplicationContextAware` is a bad thing. If `EchoingStateAlgorithm` and `ReverseEchoingStateAlgorithm` are stateless (imho they should be) and cheep to build there is no need to ask the context. Simply use the concrete implementations in the dictionary e.g. `<entry key="default" ref="echo"/>`.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, if they are stateless you can share instances among consumers of the lookup factory. Actually, in my example the `StateAlgorithm`s are singleton and I probably should have done that too. When you want the `lookupFactory` to return new instances on each call to `Create` AND configure these instances in the xml configuration, then the clearest way do this is being `IApplicationContextAware`, IMO. I'll update in a sec.

Comment: +1 A really clear solution and a very detailed answer. Thanks for sharing.